# How can I change the way the foreign key field is displayed in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

My models look like this:

```
Location:
    state
    county
    city
    street

Building:
    name
    location = ForeignKey(Location)
```

Now, in admin, when editing the `Building`, I want to have the ability to edit the Location in this way:[image: how the admin should look like]

So, it's like an inline, but with having `Location` in `Building`, not the oposite way.

Comment: Perhaps you can show a scrennshot and the admin.py code that you're using right now? Maybe you're registering them the wrong way, no?

Comment: @kovshenin: The problem is that you cannot define an inline form for Location if the foreign key defines a N:1 relation between Building and Location.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably easier to solve if you keep a one-to-one relationship between building and location. For example, by subclassing building from location or by integrating the location fields into buildings.

I assume that not many buildings share the same location. So you would not save much using a foreign key to locations anyway. This foreign key also makes editing complicated. In particular, if you want separate entry fields for location components. Normally, you would first have to search existing locations for a match before creating a new location entry.

The following example makes Building a subclass of Location and groups building and location fields into two sections of the admin form. Your application will probably require some fine tuning though.

The model:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Building(Location):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

The admin form:

```
class BuildingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('Building', {
            'fields': ('name',)
        }),
        ('Location', {
            'fields': (('state', 'county', 'city', 'street'),)
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(Building, BuildingAdmin)
```